# Correct to use "no?"

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english

Is it considered correct to use "`no`" like this :

> I loved the fair. It was fun, no?

This is the way people speak in Hindi, so converting it to English literally would not be right I guess.

Comment: "No" used in that fashion is idiomatic of several cultures.  If you wish to retain the "flavor" of the culture then leaving it that way is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I agree with Hot Licks about flavour. And in any case it is something that would usually only appear in quoted conversation, so in what context (if other than quoted conversation) would you be planning to convert it to English?

Comment: Verbally or when writing dialogues

Answer (score 3):

It is called a "[tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)" which is a grammatical structure:

> in which a declarative statement or an imperative is turned into a
>   question by adding an interrogative fragment (the "tag"). For example,
>   in the sentence "You're John, aren't you?", the statement "You're
>   John" is turned into a question by the tag "aren't you". The term
>   "question tag" is generally preferred by British grammarians, while
>   their American counterparts prefer "tag question".

The link further explains that tag questions are more common in colloquial spoken usage:

> In most languages, tag questions are more common in colloquial spoken
>   usage than in formal written usage. They can be an indicator of
>   politeness, emphasis or irony. They may suggest confidence or lack of
>   confidence; they may be confrontational, defensive or tentative.

I think it is a personal style or preference which tag question to use.

> It was fun, wasn't it?
>   It was fun, right?
>   It was fun, no?
>   It was fun, don't you think?
>   It was fun, wouldn't you say?, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it would be correct. If I'm not mistaken, the "no" in this phrase is being used like "right". For example "The party was good, right?" we use this to make the question, we could remove the "right" and all we would have would be a common clause "the party was good".

Examples:

"This is an excellent school, right?" --> "this is an excellent school"

"Out dog is cute, right?" --> "Our dog is cute"

I might be wrong, I'm not 100% sure of what I'm saying, but I don't think that this was to use "no" is correct. If you find an answer that states otherwise please let me know

Comment: This would make a great comment. (No pun intended)

Comment: The use of "no" above can be viewed as a shortened version of "is this not true", a perfectly reasonable thing to say.

Comment: In AusE (particularly in the northern hillbilly state of Queensland, and also in New Zealand), a final "eh" or interrogative "eh?" serves this function (it is pronounced distinctly "ay" (or "ay"?) in AusE, but can be a shorter "eh" when used by Maori and other Polynesian English speakers. It is used a lot, eh!